# What does the icon with the white sheet of paper with the blue arrow pointing to it to the right in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, icons, .nettiers

The icon is in the solution explorer next to one of the generated classes [image]

Comment: The icon is on a file generated automactically by nettiers

Comment: There are 34 different toolbars - you might have to be more specific

Comment: Sorry I just edited it its in the solution explorer.

Comment: I think you're referring to the icon for "Navigate Forward," which means "go to the spot in the code my cursor was just at before I hit "Navigate Backward."  Edit: if it's in the Solution Explorer, I have no idea.

Comment: @adv12 no not that one that one has a description when you hover over it

Comment: There's a c# class and then when I click the black arrow to expand the class there's another class inside of that one with the icon next to it.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if someone upvoted OP so he could upload an image of the icon... You can un-upvote after he does (it should reset the timer when he edits it in)

Comment: @Borgleader OP can post the image on imgur and then add a link here...

Comment: @rene Relevant information should be in the question, not through external links. Otherwise when those links die the question stops being useful.

Comment: I'm aware of the rules... tnx..

Comment: @Borgleader Actually a link to imgur would have been useful. Any user with 2k+ rep can take the link and edit the picture in.

Comment: @greb22 Are those partial classes?

Answer (score 2):

That icon indicates that it is a generated file.  See the [Visual Studio Image Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825) for details

Comment: Do you know how those files become a subset or "subclasses" of the non-generated file? I have other generated classes that I generated that when I add manually just show up like regular classes?

Comment: @greb22 I do not know all of the  specifics on how Visual Studio flags a file as being generated.  It does appear to auto-flag files based on file name patterns (ex: <Filename>.Designer.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Those are files (especially, resource file .resx) that are automatically generated by the designer, for instance , when you design a form with two ore more language base (localizable : true ), VS automatically generates resources files while you go through ... 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100).aspx